# How to execute Google Cloud Run service every day?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I have deployed a service in cloud run that takes about 40/45 minutes to run.
It should run everyday but I don't know how to cron it.
I have tried with cloud scheduler but I received a status DEADLINE_EXCEEDED message.
Can you recommend another service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there is no serverless service with a timeout above 30 minutes for now (Cloud Workflows, Cloud Task, Scheduler are limited to 30 minutes max, 10 minutes for PubSub).

However, even if your Cloud Scheduler log in error the invocation (because no answer has been received in the 30 minutes), your process continue to run. You simply doesn't have the retry features (retries on error, timeout, ....)

If you want to implement retries, you have complex architecture to build based on Cloud Logging, sinks, PubSub and Cloud Functions/Cloud Run to be able to re invoke your long running service (in mode "fire and forget")